# How to have a continuous border bottom on a tr with border-spacing set to seperate?

Tags: css

I need a table to have rows with a continuous bottom border, but the table cells should have a background with a vertical white space in between.

The problem is, I can't have a border that spans the full row while having a border-spacing set. How can I close the border but keep the white gaps?

Here is my markup:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
      <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
      <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My CSS defines the following styles:

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1.5rem 0;
  tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc; // This is what I need
  }
  td {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc; // Or this...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:before` pseudo-element:

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1.5rem 0;

  td {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc; 
    position: relative;

    &:not(:first-child):before {
      content: '';
      height: 1px; 
      width: 25px;
      background: #dcdcdc;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
        left: -25px;
        bottom: -1px;
    }
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/mawecotipi/edit?css,output)